# Ruby -> How to join and print multiple lines of string side by side

Tags: ruby

If I have these two multi-lined string variables:

```
x = <<-eos
11111
1111
111
11
1
eos
```

and

```
y = <<-eos
2
22
222
2222
22222
eos
```

what is the best way to print each line combined, so I would get:

```
111112 
111122
111222
112222
122222
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to take both strings and `split` them on the newline to make arrays. Then you'll have to `zip` them together so that each indexed element from the first is combined with the same index element from the second array. Next you'll want to `map` the resulting array to `join` the inner arrays you've created. Finally you'll have to `join` one last time to combine all elements in the array putting back the newlines.

```
x.split("\n").zip(y.split("\n")).map{|l| l.join}.join "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is as simple as enumerating each array and combining the values while stripping out the newlines:

```
x.each_line.with_index do |line, index| 
  puts line.strip + y.lines[index].strip
end

# => 
  111112
  111122
  111222
  112222
  122222
```

Comment: makes sense!  what does the with_index do in this situation?

Comment: In this case, `with_index` holds the index of the current line of `x` so that it can be used to access the corresponding line of `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
yl = y.lines
puts x.lines.each_with_object('') { |line, str| str << line.chomp << yl.shift }
  # 111112
  # 111122
  # 111222
  # 112222
  # 122222
```

Comment: what does the each_with_object method do in this situation?

Comment: [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) creates an object denoted by the block variable `str` and initializes it to `each_with_object`'s argument, which is here an empty string (thereby making it a `String` object).  That object is then returned by `each_with_object` after `x.lines` has been enumerated. It's equivalent to `str = ''; puts x.lines { |line| str << line.chomp << yl.shift }; str`, so it effectively saves two lines. As you gain experience with Ruby you'll find that you reach for `each_with_object` more and more.